# How to get position of listview on imageview click?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need to detect the onclick event on a imageview, and get the position to get the row from a cursor, and I don't know how.
I'm trying to modify https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/framework to and shopping cart app.

The code of the layout view where I need to detect the click event is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <odoo.controls.BezelImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_small"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_8dp"
                app:maskDrawable="@drawable/circle_mask"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/body_text_1"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cart_plus_minus_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.23"
                    android:paddingRight="5dip"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/android_red" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cart_minus_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_minuscircle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cart_product_quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                    android:paddingRight="15dip"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="18dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/cart_plus_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_addcircle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the images I need to detect the the click are: @+id/cart_plus_img @+id/cart_minus_img

When the row is click the function that capture the event is:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ODataRow row = OCursorUtils.toDatarow((Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position));
    //AddToCart(row);
    loadActivity(row);
}
```

What I need is to call loadActivity(row) when the user click the row but when click @+id/cart_plus_img @+id/cart_minus_img call another function but with the row parameter

Any help is thanksfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Tag property of the View

```
        ImageView imgMinus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_minus_img);
        ImageView imgPlus = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_plus_img);

        imgMinus.setTag(position);
        imgPlus.setTag(position);

        imgMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                ...
            }
        });

        imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                ...
            }
        });
```